# Errors in SDSS photometry

Tags: photometry, sky-survey, sdss

In plotting out the magnitude errors in SDSS photometry, I get the following pattern:

[image]

Why do the errors go up to about 0.5, then down? In other words, why does it look like a high-heeled shoe (or Italy)?

Secondary question: I'm trying to find the magnitude limit according to the $5\sigma$ method listed at [this link](https://www.cadc-ccda.hia-iha.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/en/megapipe/docs/photo.html). Would the magnitude limit be the highest magnitude in the 'sole' of the pattern, or at the back of the 'heel'?

The data comes from [VizieR](https://vizier.cds.unistra.fr/viz-bin/VizieR-3?-source=VII/289&-out.max=50&-out.form=HTML%20Table&-out.add=_r&-out.add=_RAJ,_DEJ&-sort=_r&-oc.form=sexa).

Comment: Are these data from quasars?

Comment: Yes, from SDSS quasar catalog, sixteenth data release (DR16Q) (Lyke+, 2020).